# Accessor functions by data member assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to enhance members of C++ classes so that assignment from/to them results in the call of a custom getter/setter.

Like

```
class Class
{ 
public:
    int Member;
    void SetMember(int Value); // TBD
    int GetMember(); // TBD
}
```

and

```
Class Instance;
Instance.Member= 3; // Causes a call to SetMember(3);
int Data= Instance.Member; // Causes a call to GetMember();
```

I have found a way to force a function call upon member assignment, by turning the member type to a class holding a private value, and overloading the cast operator for reading and the assignment operator for writing.

```
class WrapInt
{
public: 
    operator int() const { return Value; }
    void operator=(const int Assign) { Value= Assign; }
private:
    int Value;
}
```

This works, but in a generic way, I cannot customize the getters/setters per member but only per data type.

Do you see a way to refine so that I can write different accessors for different members of the same type ?

---

**Update:**

I have now found a solution that satisfies my needs. The members that require a special setter are defined using a class that knows the hosting class:

```
template<class Parent> class WrapInt
{
public:
    int operator=(const int Value) {  (This->*Setter)(Value); return Value; }
    operator int() { return Value; }

private:
    int Value;
    Parent* This;
    void (Parent::*Setter)(int Value);
    friend Parent;
};
```

Assigning such a member invokes the assignment operator, which calls a plain setter function via a pointer to method of the main class. The Get operation is implemented via the cast operator, which just returns the member value (the scheme might be enhanced to support custom getters, but I didn't need that).

This is pretty costly as every member takes an extra `This` pointer to the class instance and a pointer to the setter; these need to be initialized in the class constructor (if not, a crash is guaranteed).

So this takes some effort on the side of the class writer (initialization in the constructor), but then assigning to the member automatically invokes the setter, as I want.

```
class Class
{ 
public:
    Class();
    WrapInt<Class> Member;

private:
    void SetMember(int Value); // TBD
}

Class::Class() { Member.This= this; Member.Setter= &Class::SetMember; }
```

On the side of the user,

```
Class Instance;
Instance.Member= 3; // Calls the setter SetMember
cout << Instance.Member;
```

that's it.

Comment: Anything wrong with templates? Also, I do not see this as productive, it actively goes _against_ idiomatic C++.

Comment: @PasserBy: in what way can templates address this ?

Comment: Is `int Data= Instance.Member;` really such a *huge* improvement over `int Data= Instance.Member();`?

Comment: Why not just have `int Member() const` and `void Member(int value)` ? It also has the advantage of hiding your implementation.

Comment: I thought using Capitals for both types and variables was bad enough, but then I saw `class Class`. Yowch.

Comment: @BoPersson: it would break the uniformity of an existing API with dozens of classes/members which do not require custom handling.

Comment: @Sean: my question is precisely how to avoid the use of getter/setters, like is done in C#.

Comment: I don't know why you want this, but there is a way. Change `Member` from `int` to `QuasiInt`, which is a class of your design with its own custom assignment and conversion operators. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Using setters and getters is a bad practice and profanation of OOD, I do not think it is a good idea to implement that.

Comment: _"This works, but in a generic way, I cannot customize the getters/setters per member but only per data type."_ Yes you can, if you write a custom wrapper class for every permutation of custom behaviour you want. What's wrong with that? I mean practically, that is; in terms of design, there's a lot.

Comment: @Beta: this is indeed close to what I want. Anyway it will require the definition of a specific class for every member. I would prefer a more lightweight solution.

Comment: How exactly can one get more "lightweight" than specifying exactly the code needed for the behaviour you want? Do you expect the language to be psychic? How is it meant to know what you want if you don't tell it?

Comment: C#, and C++ are two separate, distinct languages, and have different features. If you want to develop in ways that C# allows you - develop in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your class `WrapInt` modifyable.

**Option 1:** At runtime, using a function object

```
class WrapInt
{
public: 
    operator int() const { return Value; }
    void operator=(const int Assign) 
    { 
        assign_callback(Assign); 
        Value = Assign; 
    }

private:
    int Value;
    std::function<void (int)> assign_callback;
}
```

In this variant, you would have to assign the correct callbacks in the constructor of the containing class:

```
class Container 
{
    WrapInt a, b, c;
    Container () 
    {
        a.assign_callback = ...;
        b.assign_callback = ...;
        c.assign_callback = ...;
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** At compile-time, using inheritance

```
class WrapInt
{
public: 
    operator int() const { return Value; }
    void operator=(const int Assign) 
    { 
        assign_callback(Assign); 
        Value = Assign; 
    }

private:
    int Value;
    virtual void assign_callback(int) = 0;
}
```

In this variant, you would inherit from WrapInt multiple times in the class body of the containing class

```
class Container 
{
    class WrapIntA : public WrapInt {
        void assign_callback() { ... };
    } a;
    class WrapIntB : public WrapInt {
        void assign_callback() { ... };
    } b;
    class WrapIntC : public WrapInt {
        void assign_callback() { ... };
    } c;
}
```

Comment: In the end I used a construction close to your first option. The callback has to be a pointer to member function.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of your code:

```
class WrapInt
{
public:
    WrapInt(std::function<int()> getter, std::function<void(int)> setter) :
        getter(getter),
        setter(setter)
    {}

    WrapInt(const WrapInt&) = delete;
    WrapInt& operator =(const WrapInt&) = delete;

    operator int() const { return getter(); }
    void operator=(int value) { setter(value); }
private:
    std::function<int()> getter;
    std::function<void(int)> setter;
};

class Class
{ 
public:
    Class() : Member([this](){ return this->GetMember();},
                     [this](int value) {SetMember(value); })
    {}

    WrapInt Member;
    void SetMember(int Value); // TBD
    int GetMember(); // TBD
};
```

Comment: Technically - `WrapInt` could be a template class named `Wrapper` - that way, it could handle any type, not just the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fight the language: C++ does not support get / set bindings to functions. You merely have to tolerate

```
Instance.Member() = 3;
```

and

```
int Data = Instance.Member();
```

Which you can provide by supplying a `const` function `Member()` that returns a `const` reference, and a non-`const` version that returns a non-`const` reference.

One criticism of C++ is the amount of boilerplate you need to write, especially if you need this for every member variable in your class. But really at that point, you are pretty much circumventing encapsulation entirely: you may as well make the members `public` unless your functions make consistency checks.

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but unfortunately the ordinary class members will not require the parenthesis. So we end up with members with and without, which will be pretty messy for the users.